# Dotnet Core How to get JWT header portion?

Tags: .net-core, jwt

I'm using JWT.NET to decode my JWT token.

With below code I can easily get the payload of the JWT, but I cannot figure out how to get the header part.

```
IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
IDateTimeProvider provider = new UtcDateTimeProvider();
IJwtValidator validator = new JwtValidator(serializer, provider);
IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
IJwtDecoder decoder = new JwtDecoder(serializer, validator, urlEncoder);

var json = decoder.Decode(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventually found an anwser myself.
JWT.NET library doesn't return header part. Use System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt instead. Hope this helps someone.

```
            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
            var val = tokenS.Header.Kid;
```